# Check if a string starts with one letter followed by digit(s) and then any characters

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I make the pattern below return `true` in scenarios like these:

`m1`, `m1a`, `M100bc`, `s45`, `S396xyz`

and false in scenarios like these:

`''`, `m`, `1`, `1a`, `mm`, `Mx`, `mm1`, `SS1b`

Pattern to tweak: `/^m\S\.*/i.test(text)`

Right now it takes any number of letters at the start and non-digits right after the first letter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use

```
/^[a-z]\d.*/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qUBCls/3). If the string can have line breaks, replace `.*` with `[\s\S]*`.

**Details**

- `^`  - start of string
- `[a-z]`  - an ASCII letter
- `\d` - a digit
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars (`[\s\S]` will match any chars).

**NOTE**: The `.*` (or `[\s\S]*`) at the end are only a good idea if you need to use the match values. If not, when used with `RegExp#test()`, you may omit that part of the pattern.

Comment: Can't `[a-zA-Z]` be just `[a-z]` since you're using the `i` flag?

Comment: @JeremyThille: Tested without `/i` first.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, that got me in the right direction. I tweaked it a little bit to work in a context not mentioned here, and it works the way I want, except that I need to enter more than one digit for it to work... `/^[a-zA-Z]\d\S\.*/i` It takes `m10` but not `m1` Ideas?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This did it, thanks!! `/^[a-zA-Z]\d+\S*/i`

Answer (score 4):

You could just test the first two characters only.

```js
var cases = ['m1', 'm1a', 'M100bc', 's45', 'S396xyz', '', 'm', '1', '1a', 'mm', 'Mx', 'mm1', 'SS1'];
console.log(cases.map(s => (/^[a-z]\d/i.test(s))));
```